# Background Image Stretched corresponding to Label Width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am struck with a simple issue in my app. In my app I have to display the points earned by the user at the top. For this I am placing the UILabel(eg: 550 points) over the UIImage.

For sometimes, it may exceeds to a big values up to maximum 8-digit score (12345678). When the label increases the length then the background Image(Green Image) also should gets expand. How can I do this?.

Comment: can u please show a diagram for our better understanding :)

Comment: Sorry @croyneaus4u, due to low points i cant able to post an image. i am just a beginner to stack overflow. It needs 10 points to post an Image.

Comment: upload on imgur.com and Just put image url

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/urZ56AY.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
    label.text = @"your points earned here";
    [label sizeToFit];
    backgroundImage.frame = label.frame;
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time the label increases the length, call `[label sizeToFit] ;` , then get the label's size to relayout your background image.